# YAML regex in configuration

Tags: regex, yaml

I'm trying to create some filters in a YAML configuration file and I'm having trouble. I need to match "Hard Rock" in one place, and "Rock" (but NOT "Hard Rock") in another one. I can make anything "Rock" (including "Hard Rock") match but I specifically want to match those separately.

For now I have this:

```
paths:

    "genre::((?i)(^.*metal|hard\\srock))": metal.hardrock/$albumartist/$year - $album/$track. $title
    "genre::((?i)(pop|rock))": pop.rock/$albumartist/$year - $album/$track. $title
```

But as it is, anything "Hard Rock" will hit the second configuration, not the first one. I have tried to add a "match words" options (\b) but that didn't seem to work.

What would be a correct regular expression to properly match those two expressions separately?

Comment: What is the exact input for this rule? Is it "Hard Rock" or "Hard%20Rock"? Did you try `genre::((?i)(^.*metal|hard.{1,3}rock))"` as a workaround? And did you try a lookbehind: `genre::((?i)(pop|(?<!hard.{1,3})rock))"`?

Comment: The strings come from mp3 tags/flac metadata files, so I would think it's a proper white space. I didn't try the {1,3} thing, will give it a shot.